# The container columns go out of the screen on small screen

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am trying to create a 3 columns product catalogue **with the intention of to show 3 columns on all screen size no matter how small the screen is**.

On large to medium size screen it seems to work very well all the columns are resized and shrinked smaller when the screen size gets smaller. However, on a small screen size the columns go out of the screen.

Here is the link to the w3school worksheet that I get stucked
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPT3QARS610C

Below is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.products {
display: flex;
width: 80%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 40px;
}

.product {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  margint-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px; 
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.product button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.product button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="products">

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="products">

   <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try to reduce the font size for smaller screens.

Comment: 1. Do you want to display this three columns next to each other or on a small screen would it be ok to display them underneath each other (not 2+1, but 1+1+1)? 2. The word tailored has a fixed width by default. If you don‘t say the word can be split onto several lines or the box with the product can go to the next row, it will move out of the screen. 3 in .product, you have margin[t]-left. 4. do you know the short syntax for margin, padding etc: `margin:top right bottom left` or `margin:top_bottom left_right`. Less lines, better readable in my opinion

Comment: @fun2life thanks for your comment, I really understand that on the small screen it would look better display them underneath each other (not 2+1, but 1+1+1). 

However, in my actual site it has around 80 products, so, if it displays underneth each other it might be a very long product catalogue page for scrolling down life forever on mobile screen.

Just want to make it short by displaying 3 products per single row.

Comment: I would probably only display the name of the product with the picture on a small screen and open the details when the customer clicks on the product. You would have to use media breakpoints to show it on large screens and hide it on small screens and then toggle the display status with javascript. But it general, reducing font size will be your first step

Answer (score 0):

The issue that doesn't allow to shrink the columns in small devices is the h1. You need to set a minimum value for h1 small devices, a maximum value for large devices and preferred value to change from small to large. For that you can use 'font-size: clamp(minimum, preferred, maximum)'.

> .product h1 { font-size: clamp(14px, 5vw, 32px); }

```css
.products {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.product {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.product button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.product button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.product h1 {
  font-size: clamp(14px, 5vw, 32px);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="products">

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="products">

   <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
```

But the better way for UX is to show one below the other. Add flex-wrap: wrap; in @media queries for small devices.

```css
.products {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.product {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  margint-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.product button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.product button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .products {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="products">

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="products">

   <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem        jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
```